# Numpy: applying a function to axis 0 of a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the function `test_outlier` that returns `True` if an `(x, y)` coordinate is greater than some `threshold` value away from a line segment that connects two points, otherwise `False`:

```
import numpy as np
def test_outlier(point1: np.ndarray, point2: np.ndarray, point3: np.ndarray, threshold: float) -> bool:
    
    line_connecting_point1_point2 = np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2)
    distance_to_line_from_point3 = (np.cross(point2-point1, point3-point1, axis=0) / np.linalg.norm(point2-point1)).astype(float)

point1 = np.array([[2],[3]])
print(point1.shape)
point1
(2, 1)
array([[2],
       [3]])

point2 = np.array([[5],[7]])
print(point2.shape)
point2
(2, 1)
array([[5],
       [7]])

point3 = np.array([[7],[5]])
print(point3.shape)
point3
(2, 1)
array([[7],
       [5]])

test_outlier(point1, point2, point3, 5)
False
```

I'd like to pass the `test_outlier()` function to another function named `count_outliers()`, which counts the number of outliers if a variable number of `(x, y)` coordinates is passed in via a **`(2, N)` sized matrix**:

```
def count_outliers(point1: np.ndarray, point2: np.ndarray, coordinates: np.ndarray, threshold: float) -> int:
    num_outliers = 0
    if np.apply_along_axis(test_outlier(point1, point2, coordinates, threshold), 0, coordinates):
        num_outliers += 1
    return num_outliers
```

I'm attempting to use `np.apply_along_axis()` to apply `test_outlier()` along axis 0.

Let `coordinates` be defined as:

```
coordinates = np.array([[7, 3, 9, 30],[5, 17, 10, 500]])
print(coordinates.shape)
coordinates 
(2, 4)
array([[  7,   3,   9,  30],
       [  5,  17,  10, 500]])
```

Calling `count_outliers(point1, point2, coordinates, 4)` results in this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In the case above, the `test_outlier` function called from within `count_outliers` would be applied to the following coordinate pairs:

```
(7, 5)
(3, 17)
(9, 10)
(30, 500)
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
def count_outliers(point1: np.ndarray, point2: np.ndarray, coordinates: np.ndarray, threshold: float) -> int:
    num_outliers = 0
    for elem in range(coordinates.shape[1]):
        if test_outlier(point1, point2, coordinates[:, elem, None], threshold) is True:
            num_outliers += 1
    return num_outliers
```